# mailing through severlet

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to email using servlet but every time it give exception although the same code
works well when it is run through simple java class. please how can i get rid of this
exception in servlet. thanks for your help. exception in case of servlet is

Exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class SendEmail
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.
java:204)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.
java:182)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class SendEmail extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
 return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password"); 
 }
        });


 try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new
                                InternetAddress("from@no-spam.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to@no-spam.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

     }
  }
```

Comment: Please post the _full_ stack trace.

Comment: Do you have a section to your stacktrace saying 'Caused by...'. Your servlet is not instantiating and I'd expect a lower-level stacktrace to be published below that you've posted above

Comment: be sure you have all java mail dependencies in WEB-INF/lib (particularly activation.jar)

Comment: i have included javaee-api-5.0.3.jar are you talking about this?

Comment: nope, javamail needs the javabean activation framework. add it to your WEB-INF/lib and you'll be allright (it's one jar usually named activation.jar, you can find it on Oracle's site)

Comment: sorry i was not here. i want to ask that in WEB-INF there is only web.xml file i couldn't find that lib file?

Comment: one thing more, does javabean activation not required in case of simple java class(not servlet)? as in that case no problem in sending mail using javamail api

Comment: I suspect you're running your program inside an IDE or you've got activation.jar in your classpath somehow.

Comment: WEB-INF/lib is a directory where you have to store runtime jars for your web application.

Comment: yes i am using Netbeans IDE

Comment: activation.jar is only needed if you're using JDK 1.5 or older.  Hopefully you're using a more recent version of the JDK.  If you're running in Tomcat, you need to include mail.jar, either in WEB-INF/lib or in Tomcat's lib directory.